# Creating a small jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this plugin to make work around an application easier.

Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/X5Squ/

My problem it that it always uses just 1 of the elements, please don't edit the data and data5 functions as these work perfectly for other parts but I need my function called jtoggle to work.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plugin you should act on each matched element and then return all the matched elements in order to [maintain chainability](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability):

```
$.fn.jtoggle = function (addUnderline) {
    return this.each(function () {
        // Do what you need on this matched element

    });
};
```

Maintaining chainability means we can do stuff like:

```
$(".jtoggle").jtoggle(true).addClass("xyz");
```

Comment: I have just tried this, can you please edit the code and send me the updated version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function (){$('.jtoggle').jtoggle(true);});
```

Have you tried using .each on this? I think the issue is that it isn't passing an array of DOM elements. I lack much experience in creating plugins, but it seems this can be easily averted by doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.jtoggle').each(function(){
        $(this).jtoggle(true);
    });
});
```

(Which would also mean that you can safely remove the .each you have in jtoggle itself)

Comment: The `.each()` is typically meant to go in the plugin so that users of the plugin don't have to explicitly loop.

Comment: No argument there. But changing this would at least give you the opportunity to test if the issue is indeed in passing the array of elements rather than the processing of it in the plugin itself.